# Automate the creation of future tasks

Tags: r, multithreading, multiprocessing, future

The "future" library is wonderful for running several tasks simultaneously on your machine and make best use of your cores.
I am trying to find out a way to give the number of tasks, n_task, as a parameter and automatically generate multiple tasks.
I hope the reprex at the end of the post gives you an idea of what I am after.
It should be a matter of writing some text as expressions to be evaluated by R, but so far I have been banging my head against the wall.
Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks!

```r
library(tibble)
library(future)


split_vec <- function(d, mylen){
    res <- split(d, ceiling(seq_along(d)/mylen))
    return(res)
}


set.seed(1234)

nn <- 12000

df <- tibble(x=seq(0,12, length=nn), y=3*x+rnorm(nn))


##what I do in the following, i.e. fitting chunks of data separately, may not make statistical sense but it is just an example to illustrate what I am after


tt <- split_vec(seq(nn), 2000)


plan(multiprocess(workers=2))

     
fit1 %<-% {lm(y[tt[[1]]]~x[tt[[1]]], data=df)}


fit2 %<-% {lm(y[tt[[2]]]~x[tt[[2]]], data=df)}



## Is there a way to select e.g. the number of tasks n_task=4 and automatically calculate

## fit3 %<-% {lm(y[tt[[3]]]~x[tt[[3]]], data=df)}


## fit4 %<-% {lm(y[tt[[4]]]~x[tt[[4]]], data=df)}


## without writing this out explicitly?
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`furrr`](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr) package:

```
library(furrr)
tt %>% future_map(~lm(y~x, data=df[.x,]))

$`1`

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df[.x, ])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   -0.04129      3.03526  


$`2`

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df[.x, ])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.1534       2.9521  
...
```